# Multiprocessing tasks sequentially with a shared value between them

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a function which loops through the indexes of a pandas df, but with each iteration of the loop, there's a inside loop which loops through each value of the df going from the start to the index's position.

n = 200k

**Outer loop:** i to n / **Inner loop:** 0 to i

In single processing, this function currently takes about 36 hours to loop through the 200k indexes.

I would like to adapt it to run in multiprocessing, but am not sure on the most appropriate implementation.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random


def processing(series):
    indexes = series.index[2:series.shape[0]]

    processed_df = pd.DataFrame(index=indexes, columns=['value', 'max_value'])

    for index in indexes:
        new_series = series.loc[:index]
        squared_diff = new_series.diff().dropna() ** 2
        integer_index = new_series.index.get_loc(index)
        sigma_sq = 1 / (integer_index - 1) * sum(squared_diff)

        max_value = -np.inf
        value = None

        for ind in new_series.index[:-1]:

            temp_integer_index = new_series.index.get_loc(ind)
            value = (1 / (sigma_sq * np.sqrt(integer_index - temp_integer_index)))

            if value > max_value:
                max_value = value

        processed_df.loc[index, ['value', 'max_value']] = value, max_value

    return processed_df


if __name__ == '__main__':

    random_list = []

    for i in range(0, 100):
        n = random.randint(1, 50)
        random_list.append(n)

    data = np.array(random_list)
    values = pd.Series(data)

    results = processing(values)
    print(results)
```

I figure I need to use Manager for the shared value (max_value) and for the processed_df, I can replace it with lists or dict and concat everything into a df after processing.

But how do I make sure that each core processing an index value is ran sequentially so that the max values are only from previously calculated indexes? Possibly using batches?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: adding the complexity of multiprocessing to perform sequential tasks, just adds processing time.  You need to rethink your logic to avoid having the inner loop, process the file from the beginning to the current index each time.

Comment: I think you should be using numpy arrays instead of DataFrame and Series. Moreover, clarify what you are trying to achieve.  I think it can be done much faster.